# Ajax call does not invoked the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im using the following code to call to controller action 
and I get interanl server error 500 in the console, the path lookes fine so what can be the problem. the entryId have value of 1...

Here is the AJAX CALL

```
$.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: "../../user/DeleteConfirmed",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: 'id=' + entryId
                });
```

Here is the controller action code

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteConfirmed")]
        public JsonResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {

..
```

The error is

```
POST https://127.0.0.1/user/DeleteConfirmed 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.1.1.js:8623
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery-2.1.1.js:8623
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.1.js:8152
(anonymous function) Index:519
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.1.js:4409
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
```

Comment: just try url as :- url: "/user/DeleteConfirmed"

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla-I define it before like var entryId = $(this).prop("id"); and I debug I see that the varible have value...

Comment: have u tried with url:"/user/DeleteConfirmed"

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla-yes the same error is occured ...

Comment: make ajax call with data: { id: entryId } and url:"/user/DeleteConfirmed" and public JsonResult DeleteConfirmed(string id) and see what happens?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not building your `data` property correctly: you are sending a string like `id=3` which cannot be parsed as JSON so you get a server error.

So you just need to fix your data: you need to crate an object with the keys of the parameter names of controller your action and you need to use the `JSON.stringify` method to turn it into a proper JSON string:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: "../../user/DeleteConfirmed",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: entryId })
});
```

Comment: Thanks I was try to change it like you write data: { id: entryId } and also data: { id: 1} and Im getting the same error...any other idea?

Comment: What is inside the error? You can check this in your browser's dev console (F12) on the network tab: you can check the details of the response there.

Comment: how can you please tell me since in the console you have error which I put now in the post.

Comment: I trying to check the response ,can you tell me if there is someting specific which I should check?

Comment: @HolgerTans I've missed something from my answer (the `JSON.stringify` part) which most probably causing your problem. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks A lot this was save the problem!why,can you explain shortly please

Comment: `$.ajax` does not automatically JSON serialize the data for you, so if you have `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` then you need to set the `data` property to a JSON string. What you can do with the `JSON.stringify` method.

Comment: instead of ``../../user/DeleteConfirmed`` use ``'Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed","user")'``